# iOS app not working on device after SSL cert expired and renewed

Tags: ios, ssl

I have an SSL wildcard that my web service uses. My iOS app works with this back end. The certificate expired and my app stopped working.

The SSL is now renewed (godaddy) but my app only works in the simulator. When loaded on an actual device, it's still not liking the SSL.

Here's the error I'm receiving:

> NSURLErrorDomain error -1012

How can I fix this and have the device work again with the new SSL?

Comment: There are multiple similar questions: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083112/how-to-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-1012-in-authentication), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607214/nsurlerrordomain-error-1012) and [this if you're using AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1328). Please post your related connection codes.

Comment: hi @Raptor thanks for that, but i want to know how to fix it with out the challenge, it was working before, is handling the challenge the only way? this was working before the SSL expired and renew

Comment: It's highly possible that the two SSL versions / specs are different. the fix is at the answers of the quoted questions above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice above, but, the fix was needed on the server, as other versions are live now...

so first I checked my certificate was not configured properly on AWS ELB,

the thing is i had to include the certificate chain,

for checking the correct configuration of my SSL I used an app called "SSL detective", and [geotrust SSL toolbox](https://ssltools.geotrust.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp),

Now basic cert and cert chain working, no need to change app.